# How to use geom_rain()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I first copied and executed the code listed on the website (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrain/vignettes/ggrain.html) to create a figure like the attached image using geom_rain(). However, I am facing with the problem that some lines do not exactly connect the dots. Could you please advise me on how to solve this issue?
[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y4jB.jpg)
(For example, the lower left point is not connected to a line)

Here is the code I ran, taken from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrain/vignettes/ggrain.html

```
set.seed(42) # the magic number

iris_subset <- iris[iris$Species %in% c('versicolor', 'virginica'),]

iris.long <- cbind(rbind(iris_subset, iris_subset, iris_subset), 
                   data.frame(time = c(rep("t1", dim(iris_subset)[1]), rep("t2", dim(iris_subset)[1]), rep("t3", dim(iris_subset)[1])),
                              id = c(rep(1:dim(iris_subset)[1]), rep(1:dim(iris_subset)[1]), rep(1:dim(iris_subset)[1]))))

# adding .5 and some noise to the versicolor species in t2
iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'versicolor' & iris.long$time == "t2"] <- iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'versicolor' & iris.long$time == "t2"] + .5 + rnorm(length(iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'versicolor' & iris.long$time == "t2"]), sd = .2)
# adding .8 and some noise to the versicolor species in t3
iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'versicolor' & iris.long$time == "t3"] <- iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'versicolor' & iris.long$time == "t3"] + .8 + rnorm(length(iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'versicolor' & iris.long$time == "t3"]), sd = .2)

# now we subtract -.2 and some noise to the virginica species
iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'virginica' & iris.long$time == "t2"] <- iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'virginica' & iris.long$time == "t2"] - .2 + rnorm(length(iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'virginica' & iris.long$time == "t2"]), sd = .2)

# now we subtract -.4 and some noise to the virginica species
iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'virginica' & iris.long$time == "t3"] <- iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'virginica' & iris.long$time == "t3"] - .4 + rnorm(length(iris.long$Sepal.Width[iris.long$Species == 'virginica' & iris.long$time == "t3"]), sd = .2)

iris.long$Sepal.Width <- round(iris.long$Sepal.Width, 1) # rounding Sepal.Width so t2 data is on the same resolution
iris.long$time <- factor(iris.long$time, levels = c('t1', 't2', 't3'))



ggplot(iris.long[iris.long$time %in% c('t1', 't2'),], aes(time, Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_rain(alpha = .5, rain.side = 'f2x2', id.long.var = "id") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("dodgerblue", "darkorange")) +
  guides(fill = 'none', color = 'none')
#> Warning: Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: alpha
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]I was able to solve this problem by setting the seed number as follows.

```
seed = 42 # number of data

ggplot(iris.long[iris.long$time %in% c('t1', 't2'),], aes(time, Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_rain(alpha = .5, rain.side = 'f2x2', id.long.var = "id", 
            line.args.pos = rlang::list2(position = position_jitter(width = .04, height = 0, seed = seed)),
            point.args.pos = rlang::list2(position = position_jitter(width = .04, height = 0, seed = seed))) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("dodgerblue", "darkorange")) +
  guides(fill = 'none', color = 'none')
```